# General term for series $0,2,12,70, 408...$

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometry, algebra-precalculus, pell-type-equations

Given the curves $y=\sqrt{2x^2+1}$ and $x=\sqrt{2y^2+1}$, the first line (line with smallest y coordinate) which intersects the curves with integer coordinates is $x+y=1.$ This line intersects the curves at $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$. Along with this it intersects the curves at $(-2,3)$ and $(3,-2)$. If we use the larger integer coordinates and construct another line $x+y = 2+3=5$ and intersect it with the curves we can find the next integer coordinates which are $(2,3)$ and $(3,2)$, but along with this we find another two points of intersection $(-12,17)$ and $(12,-17).$ If we repeat this process and find the intersection of the curves with $x+y=12+17=29$ we can find the next two integer coordinates: $70,99$. If we continue this process we can iteratively find the next integer coordinates.

So the question at hand is to find the $n^{th}$ largest integer intersecting points on these curves or in other words... the $n^{th}$ largest point of the curve $y=\sqrt{2x^2+1}$ whose both coordinates are integers. I believe by reiterating this line process we can find all integer coordinates, i.e. there are no integer coordinates that can't be found by reiterating this process. We won't skip any. (Feel free to disprove this, this is just my intuition.) Anyways, the main question to generate the $n^{th}$ term in this series, i.e. finding a general term, one the doesn't require redrawing the next line to find the next point.

Comment: Your question probably has an answer that follows from the analysis of the Pell equation $x^2 - 2y^2 = 1$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation

Comment: so there's no way to find the nth term with one step?

Comment: For $n\geq 1$, $$
\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n \binom{2n}{2k + 1}2^k 
$$ yields $2,12,70,408,\ldots$. This follows from one of the formuale in the OEIS entry for Pell numbers and the fact that you are taking every other term. You can also get it by expanding the formula given by saulspatz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would select the smaller absolute value with each pair of coordinates, thus $0,2,12,70,408,...$.

Suppose you have a line $x+y=a_n+b_n$ which intersects $y^2-2x^2=1$ at $(a_n,b_n)$ and thus intersects $x^2-2y^2=1$ at $(b_n,a_n)$.   The other intersection with $y^2-2x^2=1$ is determined by

$(a_n+b_n-x)^2-2x^2=1$

$-x^2+2(a_n+b_n)x+(a_n+b_n)^2-1=0$

The roots of this equation add up to $2(a_n+b_n)$ and by hypothesis one of them is $a_n$, so the other root defined as the next $x$ coordinate on the $y^2-2x^2=1$ hyperbola will be

$a_{n+1}=a_n+2b_n$  Eq. 1

Similarly we can seek the next $x$ coordinate on $x^2-2y^2=1$.  That quadratic equation will be
be

$x^2-2(a_n+b_n-x)^2=1$

$-x^2+4(a_n+b_n)x-2(a_n+b_n)^2-1=0$

With one root at $b_n$ and the two roots adding up to $4(a_n+b_n)$ we identify

$b_{n+1}=4a_n+3b_n$  Eq. 2

To get a recursion containing only $a_n$ terms, first increment Eq. 1 by one term to get

$a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}+2b_{n+1}$  Eq. 3

Then solve Eq. 3 for $b_{n+1}$ and Eq. 1 for $b_n$, and substitute these inte Eq. 2.  You end up with

$\color{blue}{a_{n+2}=6a_{n+1}-a_n}$

Using your initial $x$ coordinates on $y^2-2x^2+1$ you can put in the initial conditions $a_0=1,a_1=2$ and get the sequence

$0,2,12,70,408,2378,...$

matching your subsequent $x$ coordinates on $y^2-2x^2=1$.

Comment: Yep that's the recurrence relation thanks. What about the general term?

Comment: Can you solve linear difference equations?

Comment: The root of $r^2=6r-1$... Also I wanted gereneral term for the nth coordinate. So $(T_x,T_y)$

Answer (score 4):

You are looking at a subsequence of the Pell numbers - probably every other one, with some variant on the initial condition:

$$
0, 1, 2, 5, 12, 29, 70, 169, 408, 985, 2378, 5741, 13860, 33461, 80782, \ldots
$$

https://oeis.org/A000129

You can write a recursive formula but I am pretty sure there is no closed form solution for the $n$th term.

They come from an analysis of the Pell equation $x^2−2y^2=1$.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation

Comment: i know but you know how fib numbers uses the previous two terms to generate the next term (and there is a general term)... just like that i'm using a previous lines intersection points to find the next line which will in turn be next intersection. So if there is a general term? Also (i think) this is a novel way to find these terms iteratively, by using the information about the intersection of the lines to find the next intersection.

Comment: Yes, you are writing the recursion. That's a nice discovery, but It's not really new - look through the links  for the search _continued fraction convergents square root of 2_

Comment: @Sid A000129 satisfies $u_{n+2}=2u_{n+1}+u_n$, from which you can express $u_n$ as linear combinations of $(1\pm\sqrt{2})^n$.

Comment: @J.G. Yes, as with the closed form expression for the Fibonacci numbers in terms of $\sqrt{5}$. Perhaps that will satisfy the OP.

Answer (score 3):

As noted on the [OEIS page](https://oeis.org/A000129), the Pell number satisfy the recurrence
$$a_{n+1}-2a_n-1=0,\ n>1$$ with initial data $$a_0=0\\a_1=1$$
This is a homogeneous second-order linear difference equation, with constant coefficients, and it can be solved by the standard method.

The characteristic equation is $$r^2-2r-1=0,$$ which has the roots $$r=1\pm\sqrt2$$ so the general solution is $$a_n=a(1+\sqrt2)^n+b(1-\sqrt2)^n$$ for some constants $a$ and $b$.

Substituting the initial conditions into the formula, we find
$$\begin{align}
a_n&=\frac1{2\sqrt2}(1+\sqrt2)^n-\frac1{2\sqrt2}(1-\sqrt2)^n\\
&=\frac1{2\sqrt2}(\sqrt2+1)^n-\frac{(-1)^n}{2\sqrt2}(\sqrt2-1)^n\\
&=\frac1{2\sqrt2}(\sqrt2+1)^n-\frac{(-1)^n}{2\sqrt2}(\sqrt2+1)^{-n}\\
&=\frac1{2\sqrt2}\left(b_n+\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{b_n}\right),
\end{align}$$ where $$b_n=(\sqrt2+1)^n$$

Answer (score -1):

I noticed sequence you got there,
$$ 1, 5, 29 , 169 , 985, 5741, \dots \dots $$
The formula to describe their $n$th term is
$$f[n] = 1+ 2\cdot \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} { \sum_{q=0}^{k+1} { 2^q \binom{2k+2}{2q+1} } }$$
The function grows very fast, $f[0] =1 , f[\infty ] = \infty$

I compared how fast $f[n]$ was rising with $n^n$ and $n!$ though it appears to rise faster, but it soon slow down with large $n$

Comment: I think this is wrong. The growth is quadratic, as several other answers explain.

Comment: Not true, I focused on the sequence of the sum of the integer coordinates and was able to provide it's $n$th term

Comment: If the OP's sequence is $a_k$ ($k=0,1,2\ldots$) then yours is $$
f[n] = 1 + 2\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {a_{k + 1} } .
$$